# Get current logged-in user in Laravel Layout page

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel auth application in that layout page is present, So to get name of current logged-in user in layout.blade.php I have use `{{Auth :: user () -> name}}` and it gives name too. But the problem is that when i get logout and try to login then login page gives error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Please help me.

Comment: try to use it like this: {{Auth::user()->name ?? 'Guest' }} you can replace Guest word with a simple '' if you don't wanna show it.

Comment: $userId = Auth::id();

Answer (score 4):

If no user is logged in so **Auth::user()** will return null,

so in your blade you can use **Auth::check()** to verify if a user is logged in

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endif
```

More info can found in
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 3):

you can use `@auth @endauth` helper in blade

```php
@auth
     {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endauth
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check if User is logged in first
try

```
@if(auth()->check())
   {{auth()->user()->name}}
 @endif
```

or in one line

```
{{auth()->user()->name ?? ''}}
```